# Debugging local weblogic instance with Intellij 11

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Would anyone know how to configure Intellij IDEA 11 to debug a deployed "ear" application on local weblogic instance?

I am a Visual Studio  guy and used to attaching VS to an local IIS process. is there something similar here?

Comment: I'd rather recommend configuring Intellij debugger to work with remote  instance of Weblogic. This is more flexible and lets you avoid some problems that embedded Weblogic has.

Answer (score 0):

Setup would be the same as for the [Glassfish server](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_GlassFish_Server). Remote debug may be tricky to configure, local configuration would allow you to test the changes quickly and will automatically start WebLogic with appropriate options for debugging and deployment of the artifact.